# How can i customize list of Archive for particular category only in my wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I want to show Archive structure in my wordpress website

Like

```
-2014(15)
--Jan(2)
--Feb(5)
----Blog Title1
----Blog Title2
----Blog Title3
----Blog Title4
----Blog Title5
```

By default it is showing all the posts present in my website.

But i want to list out only those Posts belongs to "category=>'blog-post'" only.

I have try to use- `<?php get_archives(); ?>` but it will show list of all the posts present in my website.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95776/how-we-display-archives-for-specific-categories

Comment: I got my answer at this link thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'get_archives_where', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'getarchives_join', 'get_archives_join', 10, 2 );

wp_get_archives(array('type' => 'monthly')); //put your parameters 

remove_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'get_archives_where' );
remove_filter( 'getarchives_join', 'get_archives_join' );


function get_archives_where( $where, $r ){

    global $wpdb;

    $where .= " AND ". $wpdb->prefix. "terms.slug = 'blog-post' AND ". $wpdb->prefix. "term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'";

    return $where;
}

function get_archives_join( $join, $r ){

    global $wpdb;

    $join = "inner join ". $wpdb->prefix . "term_relationships on ". $wpdb->prefix . "posts.ID = ". $wpdb->prefix . "term_relationships.object_id inner join ". $wpdb->prefix . "term_taxonomy on ". $wpdb->prefix . "term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = ". $wpdb->prefix . "term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id inner join ". $wpdb->prefix . "terms on ". $wpdb->prefix . "term_taxonomy.term_id = ". $wpdb->prefix . "terms.term_id";

    return $join;
}
```

Yes https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95776/how-we-display-archives-for-specific-categories works. I have just presented it in more proper way.

I also found a widget for this http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-category-archive. This may also help some one (however, this plugin is very old)

Comment: This will be the one option https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-archive-list-widget/